# How to import a Deno library into a Node project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, deno

I would like to create a TypeScript library in Deno.

If I do this, how can developers using Node use my library?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in [section 8.1.1](https://deno.land/manual@v1.29.4/advanced/publishing/dnt) of the Deno manual:

> ## dnt - Publishing Deno modules for Node.js
>
> Library authors may want to make their Deno modules available to Node.js users. This is possible by using the [dnt](https://github.com/denoland/dnt) build tool.
>
> dnt allows you to develop your Deno module mostly as-is and use a single Deno script to build, type check, and test an npm package in an output directory. Once built, you only need to `npm publish` the output directory to distribute it to Node.js users.
>
> For more details, see https://github.com/denoland/dnt